Testicles referred to as scum
Went down a rabbit hole today, ended up looking at this wiki page: Criadilla

Criadillas is the gastronomic name given to the testicles, or scum, of any slaughtered animal fit for human consumption.

Why does it state "testicles, or scum" of any animal?

This question is about Spanish, not English, no?

I translated to english.  So scum would be what in Spanish?

Automated translation is not always reliable. Always check with more than one dictionary (and wiktionary is not reliable). What you quoted looks like an automated translation of the wikipedia page through google translate. And 'criadillas' corresponds yes to testicles, but 'scum' corresponds to a translation of 'latras'. The latter translates usually to blot or some kind of ugly mark. It is not too crazy to imagine some semantic shift for unusual meats to something like 'blot' or 'bad thing', but as I don't really know Spanish, it really is a matter for someone who knows the nuances.

The word 'latras' could easily be slang for 'testicles' in some variety of Spanish.

Wow, thank you Mitch. I did not take into consideration the software translation error.

Junk is, in fact, slang for such parts.

I’m voting to close this question because it's about interpreting an automated translation that is incorrect (or rather uses unidiomatic English).

@JeremiahEdwards That's always the first thing one should take into account when reading an automated translation.

Confusingly, criadillas was an euphemism,  it is an ancient vulgar term for cow's teats (tits), but the vulgarism for the bull testicles stuck. It also means potato which in Italian, patata, is a euphemism for vagina-so go and figure.

What a  hoot. It isn't scum. It's offal.

Allowing for vagaries of automated translation, it sounds like they're referring to the testicles of a butchered animal as offal, which is defined as dictionary.com as "the edible organs, or organ parts, of a butchered animal; organ meat".
Confusingly, according to other senses given in that same dictionary entry, "offal" can also mean the inedible parts of a butchered animal, or even just generally "refuse; rubbish; garbage".  This last sense may help explain why the original Spanish word was automatically translated as "scum".
See: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/offal
